# Why does sharesheet intent crash my android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_class);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        imview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        final File imageFile = new File(path, "enc" + ".png");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        imview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri urii =  Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, urii);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
            }
        });
```

The above code runs fine on my emulator, at normal speed in fact. However, when I install the apk, this activity blanks out the screen for a few seconds. After recovering, the image view works fine but when I click on the button, the app crashes. I have no idea how to debug this.

**NOTE** : This is a layout that loads after the data has been written. But I doubted maybe the data was being written slowly. So I included the file read statements within button function. But the application still crashes.

Comment: When you click, data isn't loaded yet

Comment: what is size of your image?

Comment: @AhmadHamzavi It's about 3MB

Comment: @MMG I figured that could be an issue. But this is a separate activity. This layout loads only after the previous data is written. Also, I've tried including the file reading statements within the button function, but no luck.

Comment: Use what I said as answer

Comment: @MMG no it's not yet solved. I've tried adding share sheet functionality to already existing photos as well, still crashes my app. So I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: What do you have in error part of logcat?

Comment: @MMG That's the whole point, there's no error. It runs perfectly on emulator. But on the device it crashes. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Use `coroutine` or put `progressbar` before the image is loaded completely